# Python client and server chat

Tags: python, client-server

I am trying to implement a very basic client and server chat in Python though having some trouble, the response I get is that I can only run the client or the server not both at the same time so I can't chat.

Client code:

```
#client
import socket
import time

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5454
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
while True:

      data = raw_input("Enter..... ")
      s.sendto(data,(Host,PORT))

      print "Server says: " + s.recv(1024)

      if data=="bye" or s.recv(1024)=="bye":
           print "Exiting..........."
           time.sleep(1)
           break
```

Server code:

```
#server
import socket
import time

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5454
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
while True:

      print "Client says: " + s.recv(1024)

      data = raw_input("Enter..... ")  
      s.sendto(data,(HOST, PORT))

      if data=="bye" or s.recv(1024)=="bye":
           print "Exiting.................."
           time.sleep(1)
           break
```

Also does the PORT automatically close after the program closes or do I need to manually close the PORT somehow.

Comment: On the client you side you don't want to bind, but connect. But that's not the only thing that's wrong here, have a look at the [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) from the socket docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [This](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) page there is example code for sockets, which you can easily adapt to your program.

In your script the first problem was:

```
s.bind((HOST,PORT))#for client
```

because, server binds to ip, not client, which will **connect** to the server using obviously function:

```
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
```

The other problem was that, your wasn't listening for new connection, and accepting them:

```
s.listen(1)  #number defines amount of queued connection to server
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

The last mistake was sending data to client without even being sure, if client connected to server.

Hope I helped you with the problem.
KubaBest